# Use field value (number) in main and subforms to do a calculation with date field (date) to add field value (numner) as days for new total

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, calculated-field

I have a main form containing GerminationDays (number). I have a subform where i have a PlantingDate (date). I want a textbox calculation that can add the GerminationDays value to the PlantingDate to create a ForcastedGerminationDate field. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try, please:

```
Dim ForcastedGerminationDate As Date
ForcastedGerminationDate = DateValue(PlantingDate) + CLng(GerminationDays)
```

Where the used generic variables should be your real ones...

Answer (score 0):

Bind your textbox, that shall display the ForcastedGerminationDate, to this expression:

```
=DateAdd("d",GerminationDays,[PlantingDate])
```